# Materialized Path PHP Regex to Select Last Item

Tags: php, regex, materialized-path-pattern

I'm trying to get the last occurrence of an item from a materialized path.  Below is a subset of possible values I've provided as an example where X, Y & Z can be any arbitrary string:

```
X/
X/Y/
X/Y/Z/
```

How can I select that last item on the path using php regex which would output the following for the corresponding lines above:

```
X
Y
Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$parts = explode('/', trim($url, '/'));
$lastpart = end($parts);
```

No need for regex. But if you insist:

```
#^/?([^/]+)/?$#
```

Path part is in group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a regex, use [`strrpos()`](http://us.php.net/manual/function.strrpos.php) to find the last `/` after trimming off the trailing `/`:

```
$string = "/x/y/";

$string = rtrim($string, "/");
echo substr($string, strrpos($string, "/") + 1);
// y

$string = "/x/y/z/";
// prints
// z

$string = "/x";
// prints
// x
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a preg_split and array_pop:

```
$test = "a/a/v/";
$test = rtrim($test,'/');
$arr = preg_split('/\//',$test);
$lastelement = array_pop($arr);
var_dump($lastelement);
```